# Missing keyword exception when joining 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle db and trying to join the 3 tables client, owns and account with the
following query:

```
select client.client_nbr, owns.account_nbr,account.balance
from client 
outer join owns
on client.client_nbr=owns.client_nbr
outer join account
on owns.account_nbr=account.account_nbr
```

I get the error: ORA-00905: missing keyword. What could be wrong in the query?

Answer (score 0):

You have this options when using keyword OUTER:

> - Oracle LEFT OUTER JOIN (or sometimes called LEFT JOIN)
> - Oracle RIGHT OUTER JOIN (or sometimes called RIGHT JOIN)
> - Oracle FULL OUTER JOIN (or sometimes called FULL JOIN)

So, that means you need to use something like this:

```
   select client.client_nbr
          , owns.account_nbr
          , account.balance
   from client 
   full outer join owns on client.client_nbr = owns.client_nbr
   full outer join account on owns.account_nbr = account.account_nbr
```

or what you really need for your result.

[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f41fee5fff6f64c2db7a2335fc8bb642)